# Netbeans and PHPUnit Skeletion Generator: No such file or directory

Tags: netbeans, phpunit

I use netbeans 7.2.1 and newest phpunit. When I want to generate a unit test in netbeans by right-clicking on the php class then Tools-> Create phpUnit test the Skeleton generator throws an error: No such file or directory.

```
require_once(/sharedResources/connection.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

The issue is that the path displayed in require_once is wrong. It is generatedliek this:

```
$sharedResources = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/sharedResources";
```

and should resolve to the absolute file path. This works fine when application is running in apache. However it seems that getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") is just wrong when running from netbeans. My question is how I can set it correctly? My application is under

```
getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/MyApp";
```

and the file I'm creating a test for is in

```
"MyApp/services"
```

Under Project properties there is an option web root but it is greyed out and it is impossible to set it to a folder one level higher than your application.

How can I solve this?

EDIT:

Further clarification:

I initially had a relative filepath to sharedResources which did not work also. the I changed to this one and of coruse ti makes sense it is not working as DOCUMENT_ROOT is set by apache and hence not set when running in netbeans. So a temprary fix is to add

```
$docRoot = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT");
if(empty($docRoot)){
    putenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT=C:/xampp/htdocs");
}
```

to the head of every class. of course that is not a very practical or good solution. I would need to tell netbeans to set this environment variable or to use correct relative path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is my solution. It's not ideal but simple and works. The issue is that DOCUMENT_ROOT is obviously empty when script is not called by Apache but by netbeans. Hence it must somehow be set. To do that I edited the php file `phpunit-skelgen`(it does not have a file ending but it's a php file).

Below the license text as first php line I added

```
putenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT=C:/xampp/htdocs");
```

That did the trick.